# MS SQL где запущен сервер?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

### Пытаюсь понять как устроена связь с SQL в ASP.NET

Во вкладках Visual Studio нашел вкладку, где показывает, что у меня на компьютере установлен сервер MS SQL, хотя я его не устанавливал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подключиться к нему я не могу.
Что я не так делаю? И может мне кто-нибудь ответить на вопросы:

1. Visual Studio работает только с MS SQL? (Для разработки сайта на
   .php я ставил Open Server, в состав которого уже входит MySql. Могу
   я к этой базе подключиться и использовать ее или надо устанавливать
   отдельно MS SQL)?
2. В Windows есть MS SQL сервер уже установленный при установке системы? Или это Visual Studio создала этот сервер (на скриншоте)?
3. Есть ли где гайд, а лучше видео, где по шагам все описано от (установки), конфигурирования MS SQL сервера до подключения его в Visual Studio и использования баз? (Во всех видео, которые я нахожу используют и подключаются к уже установленному и настроенному серверу MS SQL)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Visual Studio работает только с MS SQL?

Нет, можно работать с любой СУБД, для которой есть провайдеры.
Например, [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/), [PostgreSQL](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/ddex.html).

> я ставил Open Server, в состав которого уже входит MySql. Могу я к этой базе подключиться

Да, можете, если установить провайдер.

> В Windows есть MS SQL сервер уже установленный при установке системы?

Нет.

> Или это Visual Studio создала этот сервер?

Да. При установке VS инсталлируется упрощённая версия Sql Server'а под названием LocalDB.

Comment: Спасибо. Создал в проекте еще локально базу данных. К обоим подключился и не пойму, в чем разница.